# Java LinkedList removing the last node

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a Java class which consists of a node list, `WordNode`, which has the attributes of the class  `Word` and a WordNode object called `next` used as reference to the next node, as follows:

```
class WordNode
{
    Word word;
    WordNode next;

    WordNode(Word w)
    {
        word = w;
        next = null;
    }

    Word getWord()
    {
        return word;
    }
}
```

And the class `Word` has a String called `name`:

```
class Word 
{
    String name;

    Word(String n)
    {
            this.name = n;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
            return name;    
    }

    public void setName(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
}
```

I have a class which is a custom LinkedList to which I must add and remove words by specifying the word name. I am able to add without problems, but when I want to delete I have some issues. Below is the method to delete:

```
boolean remove(Word w)
{
    WordNode wm = new WordNode(w);

    if (list == null) return false; //can't delete on an empty list
    else
    {
        WordNode aux = list;

        while(aux != null)
        {
            if (wm.word.getName().compareTo(aux.word.getName()) == 0 ) //if the word to delete is found
            { 
                if (aux.next == null) //to erase the last element
                {
                    aux = null;       
                }
                else
                {
                    aux.word.setName(aux.next.word.getName()); //set current node's name to equal next node's

                    WordNode temp = aux.next.next;
                    aux.next = null; //to erase current node
                    aux.next = temp; //re-refer
                }                        
                return true;
            }
            else aux = aux.next;
        }

        return false; //reachable if word is not found
    }
}
```

Where `list` is supposed to be the LinkedList that holds all the nodes. `aux` is an auxiliary list that will cycle through the `list` to avoid un-linking. So, if I choose to remove a WordNode I compare names. It is actually removing well when the node is at any place, **except** the last node:

```
if (aux.next == null) //to erase the last element
{
    aux = null;       
}
```

I'm hoping to make that node null to mark a new end to the list, but it doesn't get erased. What could I change to erase the last element? Thank you for any help/suggestions in advance

Comment: aux = null just sets your reference to the object, aux, to null. Best way would just be to aux.prev.next = null

Comment: I don't have a field of 'prev' though. But isn't that the same as `aux = null` anyways?

Comment: `if (aux.next == null)` just tell you that your aux is the last node in the list. Setting the reference of the last element to null doesn't affect the previous node because its next node is till referencing the element you thought you deleted. That is why you need to keep track of your previous node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear the WordNode's "next" pointer. As you don't have a "previous" pointer, you have to keep track of the previous WordNode manually.

```
boolean remove(Word w)
{
    WordNode wm = new WordNode(w);

    if (list == null) return false; //can't delete on an empty list
    else
    {
        WordNode aux = list;
        WordNode prev = aux;

        while(aux != null)
        {
            if (wm.word.getName().compareTo(aux.word.getName()) == 0 ) //if the word to delete is found
            { 
                if (aux.next == null) //to erase the last element
                {
                    prev.next = null;
                    // Takes care of the case of a one-item list
                    aux = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    aux.word.setName(aux.next.word.getName()); //set current node's name to equal next node's

                    WordNode temp = aux.next.next;
                    aux.next = null; //to erase current node
                    aux.next = temp; //re-refer
                }                        
                return true;
            }
            else {
                prev = aux;
                aux = aux.next;
        }

        return false; //reachable if word is not found
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! But not when there's only one element in the list. So I added `if (prev == aux) list = null;` before `if (aux.next == null)` I tested it and haven't found any errors, but do you think I'm missing something? Thank you very much anyways, the rest of the code works!

Comment: I suggest doing this the proper way, which is adding a 'head' node. If what you call a list is just the first node and you set it to null then your list is gone. You can't insert more nodes to the list, ever. You can _hack_ your list to have a check `if (list == null) { list = newNode }` before inserting new nodes to make your list running again if it is `null`, but the thing is that it will become a new list and all previous references to it will still stay `null` instead of reflecting the change of inserting a new node.

Comment: Ah, my bad. aux is a copy of list, so setting it to null has no effect on the actual list object.

I think now that we keep a previous node we can simplify the removal somewhat. prev.next = aux.next should do the job.

Also, like marcelv said, I would put in a "head". Any decent list implementation should have that.

Comment: yeah, so I'm making my list null when there's only one element, because the first conditional of the `add` method says, `if(list == null) list = temp;`, `temp` being a temporary WordNode with the word to add. The program works now, but I'll try to change my code to include a head

Answer (score 0):

Add a `head` node.
Then in your check for last node you will have:

```
if (aux.next == null) //to erase the last element
{
   aux.head.next = null;
}
```

Comment: so, should `head` always be `aux` since it refers to the first node?